# Though I instantiated driver after calling quit(), still I am getting the following The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing "The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called" issue .Please help.

In my framework I have used the WebDriver driver variable as static.At the end of each testcase I have executed driver.quit() method.
At the beginning of the next test case I have again updated the driver variable with new instance of firefoxdriver().But if I try to use the driver variable to find any webelement the driver variable is returning null. Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
public class Frame
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver openUrl(String URL)
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        return driver;
    }

    public static WebDriver returnWebDriverInstance()
    {
        System.out.println("I am called");
        return driver;
    }
}

public class javaCheck2
{
    private static WebDriver driver = Frame.returnWebDriverInstance();

    static
    {
        // driver = Frame.returnWebDriverInstance();
        System.out.println(driver + " in static");
    }

    public static void pageMaxim()
    {
        System.out.println(driver + " in page maxim");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public static void pagesource()
    {
        System.out.println(driver + " in page source");
        driver.getPageSource();
    }
}

@Test
public class TestCase1
{
    public void TC01()
    {
        WebDriver driver = Frame.openUrl("https://www.google.com");
        javaCheck2.pagesource();
        driver.quit();

        // driver.close();
    }
}

@Test
public class TestCase2
{
    public void TC02()
    {
        WebDriver driver = Frame.openUrl("https://www.gmail.com");
        javaCheck2.pageMaxim();
        driver.quit();
        // driver.close();
    }
}
```

Output in Console:

```
I am called
FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (6df8103b-673f-954f-b20d-72fa4b9181b8) in static
FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (6df8103b-673f-954f-b20d-72fa4b9181b8) in page source
FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (null) in page maxim

===============================================

Suite

Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================
```

Please help

Comment: Not sure what exactly, but I think it is some scope hiding issue. I'm 99% sure that refactoring the code to something more readable would solve the issue (it's 2 simple test, but took a while to un-knot half of it). If you have a "global" driver variable, there is no need to create local copies also in the methods - on the other hand, if you do want it for sure, call it something else, like localDriver, or driver2, or whatever.

Comment: In Frame class   static WebDriver driver is private.So I have to get a copy of this private static in the methods as I can not directly access the driver member variable from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that `javaCheck2`'s static `driver` instance is set once (in the static init block) and never reset, so as soon as you call `quit()` the underlying Session (though not null) becomes invalid. It never gets never reset, which is why you get a failure as soon as you try to use the driver instance again.

The simplest fix to get this to work (without a big refactor) is:

```
public class javaCheck2 {
    public static void pageMaxim() {
        Frame.returnWebDriverInstance().manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public static void pagesource() {
        Frame.returnWebDriverInstance().getPageSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: After calling quit() in the TestCase2 class I am executing the given command. 
WebDriver driver = Frame.openUrl("https://www.gmail.com");
Hence static driver variable in frame class has a new instance .
But driver variable in JavaCheck2 is not initiated again as the following command is executed only once in the code.

private static WebDriver driver = Frame.returnWebDriverInstance();

Comment: After calling quit() in the TestCase2 class I am executing the given command. 
WebDriver driver = Frame.openUrl("https://www.gmail.com");
Hence static driver variable in frame class has a new instance .
But driver variable in JavaCheck2 is not initiated again as the following command is executed only once in the code.

private static WebDriver driver = Frame.returnWebDriverInstance(); //is not executed during execution of TC02.

that is why driver from javaCheck2 is still referring the old session.


This is what you are explaining ,right?

Comment: I had to read that a few times to check, but yes, that's right. If you want to refactor, I'd recommend removing as much of the static stuff as possible.